# Sourcemap Sass with Webpack (2)

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, webpack, sass

I am using Webpack 2 for building my Angular (4) app. I have it working, but I am trying to figure out how to generate sourcemaps for my scss. In my components I load my scss with styleUrls Adding the `options: { sourceMap: true }` is not working. I do not want to extract the styles for components, because then the ViewEncapsulation is not working anymore. The .global.scss I use are needed everywhere, so I do extract these and this part works fine.  Can someone tell me how to generate my sourcemaps (is it even possible with Angular)? Below is my webpack.config.js .

```
const webpack = require('webpack');
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');
const ExtractTextPlugin = require('extract-text-webpack-plugin');

const autoprefixer = require('autoprefixer');
const path = require('path');

module.exports = {
    devtool: 'inline-source-map',
    devServer: {
        port: 3000,
        contentBase: '/www',
        inline: true
    },
    entry: {
        polyfills: './src/polyfills.ts',
        vendor: './src/vendor.ts',
        app: './src/bootstrap.ts'
    },
    output: {
        path: path.join(__dirname, '../www/'),
        filename: '[name].bundle.js'
    },
    resolve: {
        modules: [ path.join(__dirname, 'node_modules') ],
        extensions: ['.js', '.ts', '.html']
    },
    module: {
        loaders: [{
            test: /\.ts$/,
            exclude: /node_modules/,
            use: ['awesome-typescript-loader', 'angular2-template-loader']
        }, {
            test: /\.html$/,
            use: 'html-loader'
        },{
            test: /\.global\.scss$/,
            use:  ExtractTextPlugin.extract({
                    fallback: 'style-loader',
                    use:[{
                        loader: 'css-loader',
                        options: {
                            sourceMap: true
                        }
                    }, {
                        loader: 'postcss-loader'
                    }, {
                        loader: 'sass-loader',
                        options: {
                            sourceMap: true,
                        }
                    }]
                }),
        }, {
            test: /\.scss$/,
            use:  [ {
                loader: "raw-loader"
            }, {
                loader: 'resolve-url-loader'
            }, {
                loader: 'postcss-loader'
            }, {
                loader: "sass-loader", options: {
                    sourceMap: true
                }
            }],
            exclude: /node_modules/
        }, {
            test: /.(png|woff(2)?|eot|ttf|svg)(\?[a-z0-9=\.]+)?$/,
            use: 'url-loader'
        }]
    },
    plugins: [
        new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
            template: './src/index.html'
        }),
        new ExtractTextPlugin('global-styles.css'),
        new webpack.optimize.CommonsChunkPlugin({
            name: 'polyfills',
            chunks: ['polyfills']
        }),
        new webpack.optimize.CommonsChunkPlugin({
            name: 'vendor',
            chunks: ['vendor']
        }),
        new webpack.optimize.CommonsChunkPlugin({
            name: ['polyfills', 'vendor'].reverse()
        })
    ]
};
```

Comment: Try to read [this](https://github.com/webpack-contrib/sass-loader/issues/309)

Comment: I read it, but they all extract their styles and I only extract my global styles.